# dojo.query for required fields

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using dojo and I need to query for all required fields in DOM and add an * next to each dijit label in a TableContainer
I've tried

```
dojo.query("[required]")
```

but it returns an empty NodeList, apparently, the required attribute is rendered to some other property in the run time

Comment: create jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for all the widgets which have required property on it directly using `dijit/registry` without querying the DOM.

Example:

```
require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry){
    var widgets = registry.toArray();
    widgets.forEach(function(widget){
        if(widget.required){
            // your code here
          }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dijit/form widgets, you can try to search for 'aria-required'

```
dojo.query("[aria-required]")
```

however its not working for all widgets (like textarea). I would suggest you use something like:

```
dojo.query("[widgetid]").forEach( //scope all widgets on page
  function(item){
    var widget = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(item); 
    if(widget.required){
      // your code here
    }
  }
)
```

And of course, better behavior should be to query widgets based on custom class not look for all widgets on page.